# NSDictionary with contents of file in Swift 2

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, swift2, xcode7

In Swift 1.X

```
let dict:AnyObject = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathURL)!
```

was working. Since Swift 2 I get a "**Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**". I searched a lot, but can't figure out whats missing.

Comment: what type is pathURL? I guess it's an optional so you need to unwrap it. But why do you declare the dictionary as `AnyObject` as you know it's a more specific `NSDictionary`. In Swift the developer is strongly encouraged to use always types as most specific as possible.

Comment: Why are you casting `NSDictionary` to `AnyObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `pathURL` is of type `NSURL`. `contentsOfFile` expects a `String`. In that case you might try:

```
let dict:AnyObject = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathURL.path!)!
```

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to vadian, just wanted to edit the question when I  figured it out...